# Check if object already exists in object

Tags: javascript

I want to check if an object already exists in a given object by only having the object.
For instance:

```
const information = {
    ...
    city: {
        Streetname: ''
    }
}
```

Now, I get the city object and want to check if it is already in the information object (without knowing the property name). The city could be n deep in the information object.

Comment: So you want to check if `information` has a property called `city`?

Comment: No, my input is the city object and I want to check if it is already in the information object. So my goal is actually getting the property name

Comment: So, you want to see if `information` contains the property `{ Streetname: '' }`?

Comment: There could also be `city2` with the `Streetname` property... All I have is `Object {Streetname: ''}`

Comment: Okay, so you want to check if `{ Streetname: '' }` is inside the `information` object?

Comment: Sorry for explaining to badly... I want to check if my input object matches an object in `information` and then get the property name | path. But I couldnt find a way of comparing objects so far

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and edit the question with more specific details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the property name of an object you can use `Object.keys()`. The first problem solved.
Now we need to iterate through the whole object including nested objects. This is the second problem.
And compare it to a query object. This is the third problem.

I assume that we have an object that only contains "simple" though nested objects with primitive values (I do not consider objects with functions or arrays)

```
// let's assume we have this object
const information = {
    city: {
        Streetname: 'streetname1'
    },
    house: {
        color: "blue",
        height: 100,
        city: {
            findMe: { Streetname: '' } // we want to get the path to this property 'findMe'
        }
    },
    findMeToo: {
        Streetname: '' // we also want to get the path to this proeprty 'findMeToo'
    },
    willNotFindMe: {
        streetname: '' // case sensetive
    }  
}

// this is our object we want to use to find the property name with
const queryObject = {
        Streetname : ''
}
```

If you use `===` to compare `Objects` you will always compare by reference. In our case, we are interested to compare the values. There is a rather extensive checking involved if you want to do it for more complex objects (read [this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects/16788517#16788517) for details), we will use a simplistic version:

```
// Note that this only evaluates to true if EVERYTHING is equal.
// This includes the order of the properties, since we are eventually comparing strings here.
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

Before we start to implement our property pathfinder I will introduce a simple function to check if a given value is an Object or a primitive value.

```
function isObject(obj) {
  return obj === Object(obj); // if you pass a string it will create an object and compare it to a string and thus result to false
}
```

We use this function to know when to stop diving deeper since we reached a primitive value which does not contain any further objects. We loop through the whole object and dive deeper every time we find a nested object.

```
function findPropertyPath(obj, currentPropertyPath) {
    const keys = isObject(obj) ? Object.keys(obj) : []; // if it is not an Object we want to assign an empty array or Object.keys() will implicitly cast a String to an array object  
    const previousPath = currentPropertyPath; // set to the parent node

    keys.forEach(key => {
        const currentObj = obj[key];
        currentPropertyPath = `${previousPath}.${key}`;

        if (JSON.stringify(currentObj) === JSON.stringify(queryObject)) console.log(currentPropertyPath); // this is what we are looking for
        findPropertyPath(currentObj, currentPropertyPath); // since we are using recursion this is not suited for deeply nested objects
    })
}

findPropertyPath(information, "information"); // call the function with the root key
```

This will find all "property paths" that contain an object that is equal to your query object (compared by value) using recursion.

```
information.house.city.findMe
information.findMeToo
```

Comment: Cool, that is what I was looking for. Didn't knew that I can compare obj with casting them to JSON strings. However this is a costly operation. Thank you Alberti

Comment: Comparing objects of arbitrary content/depth is always somehow a costly operation. Also since I do not expect that your objects are big enough that you will experience any performance issues since you only stringify parts of the objects. The recursion might be a bigger problem.

Comment: JSON.stringify({ prop1: 1, prop2: 2 }) 
!== JSON.stringify({ prop2: 2, prop1: 1 }), comparing via stringify is not going to give a reliable result.

Comment: Yes, read my comment in my code: 

// Note that this only evaluates to true if EVERYTHING is equal.
// This includes the order of the properties, since we are eventually comparing strings here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const contains = (item, data) => item === data || Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data).some(prop => contains(item, data[prop]));

const information = {
    city: {
        Streetname: ''
    }
}

console.log(contains(information.city, information));

console.log(contains({}, information));
```